# area weighted average for overlapping polygons

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use NASS county level crop data to estimate crop acreage in hydrologic regions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/how-to-use-nass-county-level-crop-data-to-estimate-crop-acreage-in-hydrologic-re)

It seems like an easy problem but I don't know how to go about it.
I have two layers for British Columbia, one divides the province into 63 polygons and the other layer divides the province into 20 polygons. What I want to do is assign the values from the the 20 polygons to the 63 polygons. Since the boundaries are not the same I would like to assign an area weighted average, so that the 63 polygons have the values from the 20 polygons depending on how much of their area overlaps. Does something like that exist or what other approach is usually applied in that case? I feel like trying to combine data with different spatial extent is a common task?

Comment: You are correct that this is a common task--this question is becoming a faq :-).  Search on [dasymetric mapping](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bdasymetric) for a small sample of solutions.  Many other threads address essentially this same question, too, but differ only in the software preferred.